# Including time variable as a fixed effect to get rid of autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, trend

Does it make sense to include time as a fixed effect along with your predictors to get rid of autocorrelation? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

It *may* make sense. It depends on what kind of autocorrelation you have. Trend is *one* possible type of autocorrelation, but there are also others.

You may want to take a look at [arima](/questions/tagged/arima). I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/), here in particular [the chapter on ARIMA models](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima.html).

---

## Longer version

Your autocorrelation may indeed come from a trend:

[image: obs trend]

[image: acf pacf trend]

Note the linearly but *slowly* dropping ACF plot that, and the PACF plot that is essentially insignificant. This combination is characteristic for a globally trended time series. (Think about why a global trend would yield this ACF/PACF pattern.)

In such a case, it makes sense to just include time as a linear covariate. Here are the residuals:

[image: residuals trend]

[image: acf pacf residuals trend]

There is no remaining autocorrelation in the residuals. Everything is good.

---

*However*, your time series may have a non-trend autocorrelation structure. For instance, an AR(1) series with a high AR term of 0.8:

[image: obs AR]

Note how if the series is at a certain level, it tends to stay at that level, but there is no overall trend visible.

[image: ACF PACF AR]

Here, the ACF drops much more quickly to insigficance.

If we fit a trend to this series, we get residuals and ACF/PACF plots that look pretty much like the original series. Which is not surprising, since the fitted trend is essentially flat - because there *is* no trend in this series.

[image: residuals ar trend model]

[image: acf pacf ar model trend]

However, suppose we fit a correctly specified AR(1) model, essentially regressing $y_t$ on $y_{t-1}$. We get white noise, which is good:

[image: residuals ar ar model]

[image: acf pacf ar ar model]

---

## R code

```
set.seed(1)
nn <- 100

obs_trend <- ts((1:nn)+rnorm(nn,0,5))

plot(obs_trend)
acf(obs_trend)
pacf(obs_trend)

model_trend_trend <- lm(obs_trend~as.vector((1:nn)))

plot(ts(resid(model_trend_trend)))
acf(ts(resid(model_trend)))
pacf(ts(resid(model_trend)))

################################################

obs_ar <- arima.sim(list(ar=0.8),n=nn)

plot(obs_ar)
acf(obs_ar)
pacf(obs_ar)

model_ar_trend <- lm(obs_ar~as.vector((1:nn)))

plot(ts(resid(model_ar_trend)))
acf(ts(resid(model_ar_trend)))
pacf(ts(resid(model_ar_trend)))

model_ar_ar <- arima(obs_ar,order=c(1,0,0))

plot(resid(model_ar_ar))
acf(ts(resid(model_ar_ar)))
pacf(ts(resid(model_ar_ar)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Auto-regression versus linear regression of x(t)-with-t for modelling time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179558/auto-regression-versus-linear-regression-of-xt-with-t-for-modelling-time-serie/179576#179576) presents a discussion of models that may have multiple trends and even multiple level shifts . Also see [Stochastic versus deterministic time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405539/stochastic-versus-deterministic-time-series/405542#405542)