# Why are regression models utilizing time anachronistic while autoregressive models are preferred?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autoregressive

I was reading the accepted answer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179558/auto-regression-versus-linear-regression-of-xt-with-t-for-modelling-time-serie) that asked what was the difference between autoregressive models and models that directly utilize time, it states that:

> Models using time or time-squared or time-cubed etc. are anachronistic and generally not used/preferred except in very simple textbooks and in very simple classroom exercises.

I imagine we are talking about models of the form

$$X_t = \beta_2 t^2 + \beta_1 t + \beta_0 + \epsilon_t,$$

where $ \epsilon_t $ is Gaussian noise and $\beta_2, \beta_1, \beta_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
The linked answer then continues

> Models using time variables will generally exhibit auto-correlated residuals thus should be studiously avoided as the presumed model.

But even autoregressive models can exhibit auto-correlated residuals so I am not entirely sure why regression models with time fell out of favor (If I am understanding things correctly).

Could anyone tell me why these models are less utilized?

Comment: I am not so sure the accepted answer is a good reflection of trends in modelling and forecasting time series.

Comment: @RichardHardy So regression models with time are used?

Comment: I do not have a great overview myself, but who knows if the author of the answer did either. To believe him, I would wish to see some evidence. As Deming said, *In God we trust, all others bring data.*

Comment: For univariate models, segmentation and then regression with time as your explanatory variable is very common.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, simple polynomials like the one shown in the question are "anachronistic and generally not used/preferred" unless there is a strong theoretical expectation that a simple form like that will work. The reasons for avoiding such polynomials are covered on several pages of this site, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/549018/28500).

That said, there is nothing wrong with explicit flexible modeling of time, for example with regression splines, as discussed on that page and in Chapters 2 and 7 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/). That allows for more local fitting of the data over the values of any continuous predictor (including time), without the severe limitations of having to uses a single polynomial to fit the entire data set. As Chapter 7 demonstrates, a generalized least squares model with flexible fitting of time can accommodate several forms of auto-correlated residuals.

I don't have data on how frequently the different approaches are used, but there is nothing "anachronistic" about proper modeling of time as a predictor while taking auto-correlation into account.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was under the impression that in some way ARMA models fixed some of the problems of regression models utilizing time in the context of time series. Would you agree?

Comment: In terms of specifics for ARMA models, I don't have much background in formal time series modeling of the type one does in econometrics. I know just enough to refer you to a superb online resource, "Forecasting: Principles and Practice," by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos. [Chapter 9](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima.html) deals specifically with such models.